# Linq - filter on multiple possible equals values

Tags: linq

I've got this:

```
vehicles = vehicles.Where(x => x.ModelUrl == filter.ModelUrl);
```

This works fine, but instead of passing a single string (as filter.ModelUrl) I need to pass a List, and the query should return all results where x.ModelUrl is any of the items in the list.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
vehicles = vehicles.Where(x => OtherList.Contains(x.ModelUrl));
```

or

```
vehicles = vehicles.Where(x => OtherList.Any(ol => ol.ModelUrl == x.ModelUrl));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vehicles = vehicles.Where(x => list.Contains(x.ModelUrl));
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome

```
vehicles = vehicles.Where(x => list.Contains(x.ModelUrl));
```

Comment: Yes of course, at any case VS intellisense helped for correct it )

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the `Where`/`Contains` approach is to use a `Join`:

```
vehicles = vehicles.Join(yourListOfUrls, 
                         vec => vec.ModelUrl,
                         url => url,
                         (vev, url) => vec);
```

or

```
vehicles = from vec in vehicles
           join url in yourListOfUrls on vec.ModelUrl Equals url
           select vec
```

which is faster for greater lists.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should just use the method [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains.aspx):

```
var vehicles = vehicles.Where(x => filter.Contains(x.ModelUrl));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
vehicles = vehicles.Where(x => list.Contains(x.ModelUrl));
```